# Foreman: operating system impossible to select

Tags: foreman

I want to add a new host on Foreman, but `Operating System` is required and impossible to select at the same time.

[image: Foreman Screenshot]

What is missing?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solution found immediately: before must add to architecture in menu "operating system"
Thanks anyway